# How do I prevent implicit template instantiations for a specific template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'd like to prevent all implicit template instantiations for a specific templated class in order to prevent it from being instantiated into every translation unit.

It looks like my options are:

1. Use **-fno-implicit-templates** on gcc's command line. This
   suppresses all implicit template instantiations, and is not what I want. I only want to prevent it for a single template.
2. Use C++11 "extern template". But this only suppresses specific
   explicit instantiations. I don't want to type out an "extern
   template" line for every potential template parameter list this
   template might be instantiated with.

So I need something in-between. It would be nice to have:

```
 extern template class Foo; // suppress all implicit instantiations of Foo
```

(Note the lack of template parameter(s).) Any ideas?

Comment: What's the use case? Are you trying to prevent certain instantiations from being used at all, or just trying to save some object file space and linking time?

Comment: I'm trying to save compile time. It makes a big difference in this case. And although I could comb through the disassembly occasionally to find any new instantiations that need to be explicitly extern'd, I'd prefer the linker just error out on any new new implicit instantiations so that they can be immediately added to the list of explicit instantiations by the person who's making the causal modification.

Comment: You could split the template definition between a header and source file like you would a non-template. Then, unless you explicitly instantiate the template for the set of allowed types in the source file, linking will fail.

Comment: Yes, I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks. Also, if I need to spread the explicit instantiations among several source files, I can put the template implementation details into a .tcc file that gets included by those source files, similar to the way gcc's headers are structured.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `std::enable_if` which does exactly this with the combination of `std::is_same` :

```
template <class T , typename = std::enable_if <!std::is_same<T,Foo>::value,T>::type >
class MyClass{
//...
};
```

now myClass won't be compiled for `Foo` type.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the answer to your question is using C++ new type traits to assert the instantiations in your constructor:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<TInstantiation, [your-predefined-type]> || std::is_same<TInstantiation, [your-predefined-type2]> /*And so on...*/, "Classname can not be instantiated using this type!");
```

It's all guaranteed to resolve at compile time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the class like you would with a non-template class. Just put the declarations into a header and include that everywhere, and put the implementation into an .inl/.i file and include that only where you want your template to be instantiated. Alternatively, use compile time switches to do this with a single file - but you do have to separate declaration and implementation.