# Is there a way in C++ template programming to throw compile time error for specific types?

Tags: c++

For example, let's say I have a function swap as follows:

```
class A {
   // all member variables and member functions are defined.
   // Given that A deleted both copy constructor and 
   // overloaded assignment operator for some trivial reasons
   A(const A&) = delete;
   A& operator=(const A &) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
void swap (T &a, T &b) {
    T temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Now I want `swap()` to work for all types other than objects of type A, this is because as I have some trivial reasons for which A have not implemented overloaded assignment operator or copy constructors.

For such cases can we write some assertion or exception handling so that we should get an error when  `swap()` function is used for objects of type A.

If we can do this in both compile time and run time, please do state the both, it will help me understanding more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent implicit template instantiations for a specific template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472564/how-do-i-prevent-implicit-template-instantiations-for-a-specific-template)

Comment: A static assert solves it for compiletime

Comment: You can also just use concepts and constraints if you are willing to use `C++20`, but probably that is overkill

Comment: Given that templates are instantiated at compile time, I'm not sure run time detection makes sense, although replacing `static_assert()` with `assert()` would work...

Comment: do you want to call `std::swap(const A&,const A&)` instead ? or `A` should not be swapped at all?

Comment: I think the compiler already does this for you. Be assured that it will make "swap() to work for all types other than objects of type A" and you will get an error, precisely because you deleted the operations used to implement swap. Now if your question is how to control the error message during compilation the problem is different.

Comment: btw `A` has no constructor, its not possible to create instances of `A` in the first place

Comment: As C++ is a statically typed language, such errors are normally detected at compile-time, as the type is already known at compile-time. It is good to detect errors as early as possible. However, if B *virtually* inherits from A, and you have a pointer-to-A variable, which actually points to a B object, you could test for the actual (dynamic) type at runtime. This could be done with `typeid` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: In case it was not clear, your favorite compiler does already "throw compile time error for specific types [such as A]", see here: https://godbolt.org/z/vvhMvPT33

Comment: If you just want to disable swap for A *specifically*, you can add a deleted function for that - `void swap(A&, A&) = delete;`

Comment: @BoP Nice idea, if that's what the OP wants, clearer compiler errors, probably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to do anything. You'll get a compile-time error if you try to use this function with a non-copyable type.

Note that [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) already exists, and does the same thing but better.

---

What you can do is make your function [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)-friendly, aka allow templates to test if your function is callable with specific types, without causing a compilation error on test failure:

```
template <typename T>
requires std::is_move_constructible_v<T> && std::is_move_assignable_v<T>
void my_swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T temp(std::move(a));
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(temp);
}
```

Note that I've also switched to `std::move` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Now `requires(A a){my_swap(a, a);}` will return false instead of causing a compilation error, indicating that `my_swap` doesn't work on `A`.